# Factor Analysis only one Eigen Value above 1

Tags: factor-analysis

I'm doing a study for HR about a certain company's interviewing style. A number of respondents were given a 7 level likert scale (1 strongly disagree, 7 agree), and I need to find out whether I can run factor analysis on these data.
Here is a sample question from the survey:

> Based on the conversation you heard, please evaluate the interviewer.
>
> a) They seemed annoyed
>
> b) Seemed bad
>
> c) Seemed full of themselves
>
> d) Ignored interviewer
>
> e) Seemed rude
>
> f
>
> g

There are 14 questions of this type.

I would like to know if I can use factor analysis here. I ran the test and the KMO was 0.9 and significant, but there was only one Eigenvalue above 1. What does this mean? What can I do next?

Comment: thanks. Variance was above 70% and scree plot cut off after 1.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing specifics (e.g., scree plot, percent of variance explained, etc.), having only one eigenvalue above 1 (using SPSS' default cutoff) suggests that the data can be reduced to one factor. I would look into what items have the highest loadings in order to interpret the factor.

Comment: ... and perhaps it is (at least partially) a method/artificial factor like answering-bias. Finding only one relevant factor would make me very seriously looking at such effects in the data. But if everything is really ok - finding one factor only means just what san says...